# How to submit data array to server from PHP and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have an array of PHP with customer data. I will modify this values in jQuery. Then O would like to submit the changed values with an Id (`cashup_id`) to the server from jquery. Please see the PHP array below. Please help. Thanks.

```
$Cashups = array(
  array(
    'cashup_id' => 146456,
    'display_time' => 'Wed 16th Mar, 9:55pm',
    'terminal_name' => 'Bar 1',
    'calculated_cash' => 389.20,
    'actual_cash' => 374.6,
    'calculated_tenders_total' => 1,551.01,
    'actual_tenders_total' => 1,551.01
  ),
  array(
    'cashup_id' => 146457,
    'display_time' => 'Wed 16th Mar, 9:56pm',
    'terminal_name' => 'Bar 2',
    'calculated_cash' => 493.3,
    'actual_cash' => 493.3,
    'calculated_other' => 1509.84,
    'actual_other' => 1509.84
  )
);
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [ajax helper functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/helper-functions/) for jQuery?

Comment: How would you modify PHP array from jquery?

Answer (score 0):

@Powtac see the JS code.

```
jQuery(function($) {

$(".Cashups").delegate("td:eq(3) > a", "click", function(event) {
var a, parent, input, doneLink, b, i, eq, c, d;
var eq = $(this).parent().children("a").index(this);

// The `a` has been clicked; cancel the action as
// we're handling it
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();

// Remember it and its parent
a = $(this);
parent = a.parent();

// Insert an input in front of it, along with a done link
// because blur can be problematic
input = $("<input type='text' size='10'>");
input.insertBefore(a);
input.blur(doneHandler);
doneLink = $("<a href='#'>done</a>");
doneLink.insertBefore(a);
doneLink.click(doneHandler);

// Put the text of the link in the input
input.val(a.text());


// Temporarily detach the link from the DOM to get it
// out of the way
a.detach();

// Give the input focus, then wait for it to blur
input[0].focus();

// Our "done" handler
function doneHandler() {
// Replace the content of the original link with
// the updated content
a.text(input.val());

b = a.text();
//c = b;
alert(b);


$.get('js_test.php?b=' + b, function (data) {                                     

    $('.Cashups td a').eq(3).html(b);

});
```